# How to use special characters like the question mark as a variable in a formula?

Tags: spacing

If i write `$t=a$` in LaTex, I get "t = a". If I write `$t=?$` I get "t =?" but I want to get "t = ?". The ? shall have the same distance from the equals sign as any other variable or letter. **Is there a way to to treat the "?" the same way as any other letter in a formula?**

To make clear how `$t=a$` and `t=?` look like, I have added a screenshot.[image: To make clear how <code>$t=a$</code> and <code>t=?</code> look like, I have added a screenshot.]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the `\mathord` command to declare an ordinary mathematical symbol, as in:

```
t = \mathord{?}
```

If you're going to be using this repeatedly, I would define something like

```
\newcommand{\que}{\mathord{?}}
```

so that you can use it easily (and be true to the semantic ideals of LaTeX, etc. etc.).

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\que}{\mathord{?}}    
\begin{document}
$t=\que$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`?`is a punctuation symbol. Try `$t={}?$`.